# Create iphone buttons to overlap UIwebView

Tags: button, uiwebview, overlay

Hi i have a UIwebview that open a google map in my app.

Is there anyway i can create a button on top of UIWebview? because currently, the  UIWebview will always overlaps my buttons.

thanks, Jon

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in Interface Builder.  Just put the UIWebView in the backmost layer, and you'll have no problem putting buttons on top.